# Return multiple values from one .xlsm file to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a macro in one Excel file to call a macro from another Excel file.

I want to return multiple values, but I am getting errors.

Here is the process flow:

macroFile1 Sub1 (calls macroFile2 Sub3 and passes arguments) -> macroFile2 Sub3 (does some process and is expected to return multiple values to macroFile1 Sub1)

macroFile1 Sub1 calls macroFile2 Sub3, but macroFile2 Sub3 does not return values.

I tried the following methods:

```
method1:

'(macroFile1)
returnCodes = Application.Run("'" & macroFileName & "'!pasteCapture", _
                  thisWorkbookName, selectedFile, cmntText, workingSheet, _
                  cmntRowNum, cmntColNum, imgRowNum, imgColNum, size, clrTyp)
```

Error upon execution:

> Compile error: Can't assign to array

```
method2:

'(macroFile1)          
Sub 1 
'(This sub is going to call macroFile2 Sub3, and macroFile2 Sub3 is 
'going to do some process, and then return values to the following Sub2.)

Application.Run "'" & macroFileName & "'!pasteCapture", _
                thisWorkbookName, selectedFile, cmntText, workingSheet, _
                cmntRowNum, cmntColNum, imgRowNum, _
                imgColNum, size, clrTyp

'thisWorkbookName is the absolute path of the file containing macroFile1. 
'I am passing this to 'macroFile2 Sub3 so that I can call 
'macroFile1 Sub2 from macroFile2 Sub3.

End Sub

Sub 2 
'(I wrote this sub so that I can receive return codes from macroFile2 Sub3. 
'This sub is right below
'macroFile1 Sub1.)

Sub getReturnCodes(extError, fileNotFound, opnError, worksheetNotFound, _
              rowNotNumeric, rowOutOfScope, colNotNumeric, colOutOfScope, _
              sizeNotNumeric, sizeOutOfScope, incorrectClrTyp, success)

If success = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Successful", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "Error", vbOKOnly
End If

End Sub

'(macroFile2)
Sub 3 
'(This sub will receive multiple arguments from macroFile1 Sub1, 
'process them, and call macroFile1 Sub2 to pass multiple return values.)

'Some process...

Application.Run "'" & calledBy & "'!getReturnCodes", _
           extError, fileNotFound, opnError, worksheetNotFound, rowNotNumeric, _
           rowOutOfScope, colNotNumeric, colOutOfScope, sizeNotNumeric, sizeOutOfScope, _
           incorrectClrTyp, success

End Sub
```

Error upon execution:

> The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
>   disabled

I want to pass multiple values as return values to macroFile1. I am allowed to pass them to either Sub1 or Sub2 (I have also tried to change Sub2 to function, but the error occurred at `Application.Run`).

Comment: Is this correct ?. You have 2 workbooks called macro1.xlsm and macro2.xlsm. In macro1.xlsm you have 2 subs one of which is called getReturnCodes. In macro2.xlsm you have a sub called pasteCapture. macro1!Sub1 calls macro2!pasteCapture(passing various parameters). macro2!pasteCapture does something and calls macro1!getReturnCodes(more parameters). macro1!getReturnCodes shows user with a msgBox the status parameter. (Q1) Where are the subs located, on a sheet, workbook level or in a module ? 
(Q2) Are both macros in the same folder.

Comment: Hi... Sub1 and Sub3 are at worksheet level (macro1), and Sub2 is in a standard module (macro2)... Could it be possible that Sub1 can call Sub2 because Sub2 is in a module, but Sub2 cannot call Sub3 because Sub3 is in a worksheet? I am trying to figure it out on my PC at home, and the actual program is in the office... I am not allowed to bring it home.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hint... It works when I place my program in a module. Can't wait to go to office on Monday and try them with the actual files!

Comment: If the macro is in sheet1 you could use "!sheet1.subname", the same reference as shown on the top of the developer screen but they are probably better in a module.

Comment: Hi... I changed the macro address to !sheet1.subname and now it's working perfectly fine!! I want to mark your answer with a tick mark. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me

In RunIt.xlsm:

```
'Calls "DoSomething" in workbook "Callee.xlsm", and passes in a callback
Sub Start()
    Dim CallBack As String

    CallBack = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!CallbackTarget" 

    Application.Run "Callee.xlsm!DoSomething", CallBack, "hello", "there"

End Sub

'Called from "DoSomething" in "Callee.xlsm" to return some values, using the callback
Sub CallBackTarget(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    Debug.Print "In CallBackTarget", arg1, arg2, arg3
End Sub
```

In Callee.xlsm:

```
Sub DoSomething(CallBack, arg1, arg2)

    Debug.Print "In DoSomething", arg1, arg2
    'do some work...
    Application.Run CallBack, "someValue", 44, "otherValue"

End Sub
'----------------------------------------
```

---

However, you could simply return an array of values to `Start` directly from `DoSomething` (after making it a Function) and that would be much simpler:

Calling workbook:

```
Sub TestGetArray()
    Dim arr
    arr = Application.Run("Callee.xlsm!GetArray")
    Debug.Print arr(1)
End Sub
```

Called workbook:

```
Function GetArray()
    GetArray = Array("one", "two", "Three")
End Function
```

---

One more approach while we're on the subject: this one allows you to forget about `Run` alltogether.

In the called workbook's `ThisWorkbook` code module (note these methods are `Public`):

```
Public Sub DoSomething(arg1, arg2)
    Debug.Print "Called with:", arg1, arg2
End Sub

Public Function ReturnSomething(arg1, arg2)
    ReturnSomething = "Returning: " & arg1 & ", " & arg2
End Function

Public Sub ReturnValuesByRef(v1, v2)
    v1 = "new"
    v2 = "value"
End Sub
```

In the calling workbook:

```
Sub TestDirectCalls()

    Dim wb As Object  
    Set wb = Workbooks("Callee.xlsm") 'Get a reference to the workbook
                                      '  you want to call methods in

    wb.DoSomething "value1", 25                     'call a sub

    Debug.Print wb.ReturnSomething("value1", 25)    'call a function

    Dim v1, v2
    wb.ReturnValuesByRef v1, v2           'return values via byref args
    Debug.Print "Returned - ", v1, v2

End Sub
```

Here you're calling methods directly on the other workbook, avoiding some of the limitations of `Application.Run`.

Comment: Hi Tim! Thanks again... I am now suspecting that Sub1 can call Sub2 because Sub2 is in a module, but Sub2 cannot call Sub3 because Sub3 is in a worksheet. I am trying to figure it out on my PC at home, and the actual program is in the office... I am not allowed to bring it home. I will get to know latest by Monday morning!

Comment: Hi Tim, both solutions are working on my PC (after I wrote Sub1 and Sub3 in a module)... Can't wait to go to office on Monday and try them with the actual files!

Comment: Hi TIm, I could pass a single value to Start directly from DoSomething (after making it a Function), but could not pass an array... Can you please help me? I am sorry, to bother you with this, but I am still a beginner :(

Comment: Hi Tim, I am getting error 40036 when I try to execute this line > wb.DoSomething "value1", 25                     'call a sub I have only replaced the arguments before executing... (I have placed the code in 'ThisWorkbook' of the called workbook and made all subs and functions public)

Comment: BTW, I could pass an array of return values! Thanks a ton :) Now I am struggling to make it work by following the steps in your second solution, i.e. avoiding Application.Run

Comment: Please update your question to add the code you're trying.  I can't see what you have.

Answer (score 0):

If the macro is in sheet1 you could use "!sheet1.subname", the same reference as shown on the top of the developer screen.