# VBA global variable and access across workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I am trying to get two separate workbooks to interface with one another.  In "workbook1.xlsm", cell C6 can be changed by an input from the user, (i.e. changing the order status of an item).

This section of code is under module 1 of "workbook1.xlsm".  It gets the content of cell C4 and sets it to the variable "strText".  I believe using "Public strText As String" will make it a global variable.

```
Public strText As String


Sub module1()
   strText = Cells(4, 3).Value
   MsgBox strText
End Sub
```

Next, module1 in "workbook2.xlsm" has its own spreadsheet where I would like to have the "strText" variable in "workbook1.xlsm" be able to be accessed so that I can fill in various cells in "workbook2".
The code for module1() of "workbook2.xlsm" I think would look something like,

```
Sub module2()
   range("A1").Value = strText 
end sub
```

Therefore, this would just populate A1 through the "strText" global variable.  I understand this could be done by simply putting an "=" in the cell and then clicking on the corresponding workbook and corresponding cells but it is important that I get the values from the global variable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Previous Q on transferring information between workbooks - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008669/478884

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are global only to the Workbook they are declared.

But you don't need it anyhow: You can access the value of any cell of any sheet of any open workbook. You just need to tell VBA which workbook and -sheet you want to access.

So your Sub `module1` is not needed at all (btw: Be carefull with the name, a Sub may not have the same name as a Module, else you will get strange errors).

Your Sub `module2` (again, be carefull with that name) could look like

```
Sub module2()
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Workbooks("workbook1.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(4, 3)
End Sub
```

`ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where your code is stored. Note that you always should specify the Sheet that you want to access, in my example I use the first sheet of both workbooks - up to you to change that to your needs.

Comment: Oh snap ok, that helped connected the workbooks.  However, I need to manually run the VBA for the changes to take place.  Is there a way for a cell in one workbook to be changed and it correspondingly auto changes in the connected workbook?

Comment: Is that "connected" workbook already open when the code is run? It sounds like maybe an actual database would be better for your needs if you need to be able to do things like this.

Comment: Re _Is there a way for a cell in one workbook to be changed and it correspondingly auto changes in the connected workbook_ that's why you'd use a Formula, rather than vba. You said in the Q _it is important that I get the values from the global variable_ : perhaps explain why that is.  There may be alternatives you haven't considered